# Wordpress alternative to using GET?

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have a plug in that displays the images of the authors that blog for my site.

The plug-in is as follows:

```
function display_authors() {
    global $wpdb;
    $authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from $wpdb->users ORDER BY display_name");


    $output = '<ul id="authors">';

    foreach($authors as $author) {

        if($author->display_name != 'admin')
        {
            // display user image for each author
            $output .=  '<li class="author" id="author-'.$author->ID.'">';
            // userphoto function echoes image HTML rather than returning it
            $output .= userphoto($author->ID);
            $output .= '</li>';
        }
    }   

    $output .= '</ul>';

    echo $output;
}

add_shortcode('oe-list-authors', 'display_authors');
```

What I am wondering is how to link to a page where I will show some of the author's meta content and their latest posts etc.

I want this to be the same page because it needs to have the same parent in the nav bar.

Normally in PHP, you could check if there was a `GET` variable set so that you could either show the list of authors and the page content that goes with it, or the profile information for a particular author but I have no idea how to do it within the confines of Wordpress and I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I think you can still access GET variables using `$_GET['varname']`

See this page:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-custom-_get-variables-with-templates-and-permalinks

So have you tried:

```
$whatever = $_GET['somevar'];
```

?

Comment: NOTE: Don't use 'p' as a variable name!

Comment: thanks, for some reason I thought there would be a 'wordpress way' of doing it but this seems to work when I thought it wouldn't!